# 403 Forbidden on wamp with vmware

Tags: phpmyadmin

I get "403 forbidden error"  when trying to open localhost (phpMyAdmin).

I have VMware installed on my computer and also my phpMyAdmin configuration file is not a text file but a VMware config file (mentioning this because I tried to go to wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf file to modify parameters but ended up not being able to open it as it was not text file).

Comment: Does your webserver error log contain any hints? Did you check that the file permissions are set so that the webserver has access to the phpMyAdmin files?

Comment: Also as far as opening the file, I presume your operating system has associated .conf files with VMWare; you should still be able to open it in your text editor directly (though there's nothing in the native phpMyAdmin configuration that should cause this error; though I don't know what WAMP might have done).